# Eclipse context menu corrupts when i am adding icon images

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

Everytime i am adding an extension point for context menu contribution to my eclipse plugin, the context menu is corrupted like in the screenshot:
[image]

I am using normal **GIF** images for the menu icons. Have you got an idea why this is happening.
This is how i define the context menu entry:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">   
  <menuContribution
     locationURI=
     "popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">                    
     <menu
           icon="icons/zf_logo_mini.gif"
           label="MyProject">               
            <command
                 commandId="MyProjekt.commands.AddComponent"
                 icon="icons/add_obj.gif"
                 label="Sample Entry"
                 tooltip="Sample Entry">
            </command>
     </menu>
</menuContribution>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refresh the whole workspace and determine, wether there are some interferrences with some other plugins like cdt